# Wildfly 10 - HSQL Datascource - null pointer excception testing connection to database

Tags: datasource, wildfly, wildfly-10

I would like to know if anybody is aware of the following problem in wildfly 10.

When trying to setup a datasource for HSQL, I was confronted with the problem  where for a non xa data source driver, you would expect the configuration element `connection-url` to be of any use. In particular, this configuration element is of use when you attempt to connect to H2 or oracle.

However, when testing the following configuration I was systematically hitting a null pointer exception on HSQL getConnection.

The hsql modulue is added as jboss module with:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.hsql">
    <properties>        
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hsqldb-2.3.2.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

The original configuration of the datasource, the one that does not work was as follows:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/HSQL_NON_JTA_DS" pool-name="HSQL_NON_JTA_DS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/DATABSE</connection-url>
    <datasource-class>org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource</datasource-class>    
    <driver>hsql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>USER</user-name>
        <password>USER</password>
    </security>
</datasource>


<driver name="hsql" module="org.hsql">
    <datasource-class>org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

With the following stack trace:

```
2017-03-01 18:08:47,083 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (thread: management task-6) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:350)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:285)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1319)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:1061)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:234)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1344)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:392)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:217)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:212)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:95)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:312)
    ... 31 more
```

This null pointer exception happend, quite simply because.
In the JDBCDataSource.java of HSQL, the following method was getting a null URL.
Meaning, JBOSS had not picked up the URL on the connection-url and configured on the driver.

```
private Connection getConnection(String url,
                                     Properties props) throws SQLException {

        if (!url.startsWith("jdbc:hsqldb:")) {
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:" + url;
        }

        return JDBCDriver.getConnection(url, props);
}
```

NOTE: If you want to debug HSQL you need to use the -debug.jar files that HSQL releases internally.
In any case...

After finding out that the subsytem for data sources is provided by IRON JCAMAR, it was possible to hunt the documentation for extra configuration properties to work-around what should never have been a problem.

Here is the documentation on elements supported for the data-source.
http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.1/en-US/html_single/index.html#deployingds_descriptor

Ultiamtely, to make the connection work It was necessar to enrich it with the following element.

```
<connection-property name="url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/DATABSE</connection-property>
```

Does it make any sense that additional element was necessary? It should have been redundant and unecessary. It is a good thing that custome data source properties are to be supported.

In this case, Is the problem with HSQL or is the problem with JBOSS.
In eery other app server, specifying the connection URL has always worked fine.
To me this appars to be a particular behavior of Wildfly.

This quite a problem since your average documentation on data sources just makes it abundantly clear that the connection-url is the element you do need to configure. In this case, it really is not.

Many thanks for a reply on this.

Comment: Have you installed HSQL driver in modules?

Comment: Yup, I did. modules\org\hsql\main\modules.xml and hsql jar are in there. I believe this cannot have anything to do with where you put the HSQL driver. This must have to do with the implementation logic of the JBOSs layer that is configuring the driver. Since the work-around worked, it means that the Jboss is calling a JBDDataSource getConnection() api without beforehand have passed in the configured connection URL. But when you specify connection sproperties, JBOSS configures the data source with those properties. To me it looks like an implementation bug on Jboss, but i could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like configuration issue.  Update module name to `org.hsqldb` in datasource and module.xml file to follow standard module naming conventions.  Update directory name from **hsql** to **hsqldb** under modules directory. It's all up to you. You can use your custom module naming convention too.

Some of the drivers does not have `getURL()` method implemented in their datasource classes. So, we have to specify datasource configuration differently for them.

Like Postgres, does not have getURL method. So, we will specify properties like this in our stanalone.xml/domain.xml file.

```
<xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">DatabaseHostName</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">DatabasePortName</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">DatabaseName</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-class>com.edb.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
<driver>postgresql</driver>
<security>
     <user-name>database.username</user-name>
     <password>database.password</password>
</security>
```

Whereas in case of Oracle which has `getURL` method implemented, configuration given below works fine.

```
<xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@database.host:database.port:database.name</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
<driver>oracle</driver>
```

I  am not sure about HSQL driver implementation of `getURL` API. You can try specifying properties like I mentioned for Postgres and check if it works for your use-case.

Comment: Why would that change anything?
Sorry I will note even test this. Jboss does not care you call your modules as long as you are consistent. And I am consistent everywhere.
I could name the module: why.would.i.need.to.follow.your.namming.convention and put it in a corresponding folder stracuture. As long as the module naming is consistent everywhere you can call your module whatever you want.

Comment: It's a standard practice to name of the module coincides with the embedded top package. You can name your.module.blah.blah.or.anything.you.want. But if you check all the existing modules they follow standard practice.  I will update my answer and I hope this will help your in resolving your issue.

Comment: Hi, the source code of HSQL JbdcDatasource implements getUrl and getURL. Everything appears to be there.

The properties you illustrate as example, are in this case for XA data sources. They are logically similar, in any case.

In my opinion the Wildfly documentation is clearly lacking on the department of datasource configuration, because the examples they illustrate make it abundantly clear the JDBC URL should primarly be originating from the connection-url element.  The UI wizard is not usable for HSQL. So documentation and user interface, really leave you with no good alternatives.